# How to handle Null returned from JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have a `JSON` which might contain `null` values in values for some keys.

This is the code I have:

```
static func parseJSONString(jsonString: String?, key: String?) ->  () -> String{
        var jsonSubString: String?
        func parseString() -> String{
            if let data = jsonString?.data(using: .utf8){
                if let content = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []),
                    let array = content as? [[String: AnyObject]]
                {

                    for jsondict in array {
                        if let jsondictOptional = jsondict[key!]{
                            jsonSubString = (jsondictOptional as? String)
                        }
                        else {
                            jsonSubString = " "
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            return jsonSubString!
        }
        return parseString
    }
```

When I run the app, it crashes. How do I run this code successfully so that I can even handle `nulls` returned from JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the crash is that you are force unwrapping an optional. If the optional is `nil` it will crash your application. You can fix it by making your function return an optional `String` instead of force unwrapping it or by returning an empty `String` when it's `nil`.

```
static func parseJSONString(jsonString: String?, key: String?) ->  () -> String? {
        var jsonSubString: String?
        func parseString() -> String{
            if let data = jsonString?.data(using: .utf8){
                if let content = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []),
                    let array = content as? [[String: AnyObject]]
                {

                    for jsondict in array {
                        if let jsondictOptional = jsondict[key!]{
                            jsonSubString = (jsondictOptional as? String)
                        }
                        else {
                            jsonSubString = " "
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            // Don't force unwrap this
            // You could use `return jsonSubString ?? ""` if you want an empty string if the value is null
            return jsonSubString
        }
        return parseString
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get, why you want something like that. I mean, you only get the last value from your JSON array for the corresponding key. And why would your key be optional. And why would you return a closure instead of the value. But I fixed your example in accordance with the original post behavior, just without crashes:

```
extension Dictionary {
    subscript(key: Key?) -> Value? {
        return key.flatMap { self[$0] }
    }
}

public func cast<Type, Result>(_ value: Type) -> Result? {
    return value as? Result
}

typealias JSONArray = [[String: AnyObject]]
func toJSONArray(x: Any) -> JSONArray? {
    return cast(x)
}

let json = "[{\"value\":\"1\"}, {\"value\":null}]"

func parseJSONString(jsonString: String?, key: String?) ->  () -> String {
    return {
        jsonString?.data(using: .utf8)
            .flatMap { try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: $0, options: []) }
            .flatMap(toJSONArray)
            .flatMap { xs in
                xs.flatMap { $0[key] }
            }
            .flatMap { cast($0.last) }
            ?? ""
    }
}

let a = parseJSONString(jsonString: json, key: "value")()

print(a)
```

You can get the cast function from [IDPCastable cocoapod](https://github.com/idapgroup/IDPCastable). And you should read more about [type inference](http://blog.idapgroup.com/type-inference).

In order to make flatmaps more brewable check out SwiftZ cocoapod.

BTW, in the accepted solution, if key is nil, your function would also fail.